# At least one object must implement IComparable

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

```
var listair = empcon.OrderBy(x => x.CustomerConnection.OrderBy(y => y.Id)).ToList();
```

When I am using this statement then I am getting exception "At least one object must implement IComparable"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well the code you posted isn't enought. What's empcon? What's CustomerConnection? You should provide more details.

Answer (score 26):

I had this problem with my query when I wrote it wrong:

```
IEnumerable<OrgRelation> relations = from r in tree.OrgRelations
                                                 orderby r.ParentUnit, r.ChildUnit
                                                 select r;
```

This was because the Parent and Child Units are both OrgUnit objects the are related to this OrgRelation entity. What I needed was to order not by the object, but by the property of the object on which I really wanted to sort. When I added the ".Name" it worked.

```
IEnumerable<OrgRelation> relations = from r in tree.OrgRelations
                                                 orderby r.ParentUnit.Name, r.ChildUnit.Name
                                                 select r;
```

Comment: yes because when using the Name this is a string and IComparable is already implemented on strings.

Answer (score 8):

Implement IComparable for the Types of the objects contained by CustomerConnection and empcon.  If they don't have IComparable implemented then there is no way to perform an order by.